# Can ping via hostname and ip but only curl via ip inside docker network

Tags: docker, networking

I have three containers that are in the same network: one running WordPress, one running a custom application, and one running Nginx. Nginx is the proxy for both. I can access WordPress and the custom application from the Nginx container and the host (via Nginx).

What I cannot do is access WordPress via Nginx from my custom application. All three containers are in the same network. I can ping the Nginx Container from the application via a custom hostname `foo.bar.localhost` (localhost just because this is also the hostname in my dev setup) and it gives me the correct IP of the container in the correct network. I also can curl Nginx from my custom application, but I cannot curl the hostname:

```
# curl http://foo.bar.localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to foo.bar.localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

# ping foo.bar.localhost
PING foo.bar.localhost (192.168.48.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.48.4: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.229 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.48.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.439 ms

# curl 192.168.48.4
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
[...]
```

If something would be wrong with DNS or the connection itself, pinging the hostname would fail, and if port 80 would be closed, the curl would fail, so where is the problem?

**Update**

This is a minimal example but in this example, everything works as expected, so I am now searching for the differences in both projects.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  example:

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:6-fpm
    networks:
      example:
        aliases:
          - wordpress
  app:
    image: ubuntu:22.04
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    networks:
      example:
        aliases:
          - app
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - app
      - wordpress
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      example:
        aliases:
          - nginx
          - wordpress.example.localhost
```

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name wordpress.example.localhost;

    index index.php index.html;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name app.example.localhost;

    # Irrelevant
}
```

```
# docker compose exec -u root app bash
# apt update && apt install -y inetutils-ping curl
# curl -I wordpress.example.localhost
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

**Update 2**

`dig` did show me that the container can resolve the hostname:

```
# dig wordpress.example.localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.18.19-1~deb12u1-Debian <<>> wordpress.example.localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10135
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wordpress.example.localhost.   IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wordpress.example.localhost. 600 IN A   192.168.48.4
```

but `curl` did not:

```
# curl -vvv wordpress.example.localhost
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
```

Then I thought it might be curl-related (https://serverfault.com/questions/335359/how-is-it-possible-that-i-can-do-a-host-lookup-but-not-a-curl) and it was, `wget` with ipv4 did work, but neither ipv4 nor ipv6 did work with curl.

The issue is still not fixed but I leave it at that.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] -- for example, a compose file that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @larsks Minimal example included, "sadly" it works in the example. But I think I can find the issue, now that I know that it should work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a distribution issue where curl could not resolve the hostname ending with localhost (while e.g. dig could resolve the hostname). I changed the tld from localhost to local and everything worked fine.